# Getting current location (Latitude and Longitude) from my ASP.NET App

Tags: asp.net, gps, location-services, google-location-services, uwp-maps

There are similar questions asked getting lat and lang values for my current location.
How to get the current lat and lang values from my ASP.NET App.
If that is not possible, how to get the value from UWP App?
Any pointers are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Check this out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: Looks promising, i will take a look.